# Java deck of cards

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to get a piece of Java to return a int total of the value of the cards in a deck. Using a test data of 10 cards of different values I should get the result 64 but I'm getting random answers around 73 but every time i run it, it changes slightly. Anyone got any ideas why?? I am also confused with a piece of the program as i am trying to return an array of all the cards of a certain suit(in the test case its hearts). If my code is very messy or completely wrong its because I'm just a beginner haha. All the methods and stuff have already been completed by my lecturer im just trying to get someone to show me in the right direction for the methods.

Thanks in advance.

***1st question***

```
public int totalPack() {

    int total = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < pack.size(); i++){
        total = total + pack.get(i).getNumber() ;
         }
    return total;
    }
```

**end**

**2nd question**

```
public ArrayList<Card> findSuit(String suit) {

    for ( int i = 0; i < pack.size(); i++){
        if (pack.get(i).getSuit().equals(suit)){
    return null;
        }
        else return ???;
    }

    return findSuit(suit);

}
```

Comment: Where is the portion of your code concerning "pack"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Ask **one** question per question, not two, and include the minimum **complete** necessary information, which in this case clearly includes the declaration of `pack` and probably the `Card` class as well. *(not my dv)*

Comment: Got it sorted thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

For your second question:

As Jurfer mentions, you don't need recursion. You need to follow four simple steps:

- Create a new ArrayList
- Iterate over all cards
- Check whether each card is of the desired suit, and if so add it to the ArrayList
- Return the ArrayList.

Check the code:

```
public ArrayList<Card> findSuit(String suit) {

  // 1. Create a new ArrayList   
  ArrayList<Card> list = new ArrayList<>();

  // 2. Iterate over the cards
  for ( int i = 0; i < pack.size(); i++){
    // 3. If the card is of the desired suit  
    if (pack.get(i).getSuit().equals(suit)){
         // add it to the list
         list.add(pack.get(i));
    }
    // 4. Return the ArrayList
    return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first part we need to see the rest of your code.

As for the second part:

Firstly, you need to change what you return if you pack size is equal to 0, where you have:

```
return findSuit(suit);
```

If this case is hit, you will get stuck in an infinite recursion and get an overflow error of some sort. You should have just returned something to the console or thrown an error here saying pack size is invalid, below is a better solution.

Then, to solve your problem, I suggest instantiating a new ArrayList and called it suitMatchList (or whatever you find relevant) and when the card you are looking at in the pack matches the suit you want, add this to the new ArrayList<>, you don't need the else statement and you also need to remove the returns inside the for loop as it will only loop once. You seem to have tried to tackle this with a mixture of loops and recursion, but confused both. Use one or the other.

Then once the for loop has completed, you can return this new ArrayList<>.

Hope this helps. Give it a go and if you are still stuck let me know and I'll add some code.

**EDIT:**

I have added the code below, but still give it a try first :)
I have just written this off the top of my head without an IDE, so it might by syntactically incorrect, but I think it's right.

```
public ArrayList<Card> findSuit(String suit)
{
    ArrayList<Card> matchSuitList = new ArrayList<Card>();

    for (int i = 0; i < pack.size(); i++)
    {
        if (pack.get(i).getSuit().equals(suit))
        {
            matchSuitList.add(pack.get(i));
        }
    }

    return matchSuitList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I thought that you had to create a new array to store the values but wasn't 100% sure how to do it :-)    Also what parts of the code would be required for the first question? Or would it be easier to save a copy in a zip file if thats possible? Ive got different methods in different classes so I'm assuming thats what you need to able to see?

Comment: EDIT: I realised I've made a stupid mistake and figure out my problem in q1, silly me haha! Thanks a bunch for the help Matt and Jurfer!